# ipfs - How can I download and seed a file?

Tags: ipfs

I can download a file with `ipfs get hash` but does that seed the file too? It also downloads a copy of the file and saves it to the folder I run the command from which I don't want. I only want the file to be chopped up and seeded from .ipfs

Answer (score 4):

Any files accessed through your gateway will be cached and available (seeding) to the rest of the p2p network as long as your daemon is running and publicly accessible.

You can run `ipfs repo gc` to clear your cache.

You may also add files to your local storage that won't be garbage collected. You can do this with `ipfs pin {hash}`, and you can view the pinned items with `ipfs pin ls`.

Comment: More precisely, `ipfs pin ls --type=recursive`. Otherwise, you'll have hashes that are just part of a larger file.

Comment: `ipfs pin add <ipfs-path>` - Pin objects to local storage.
`ipfs pin ls [<ipfs-path>]` - List objects pinned to local storage.
`ipfs pin rm <ipfs-path>` - Remove object from pin-list.

More information - [ipfs pin](https://docs.ipfs.tech/reference/kubo/cli/#ipfs-pin).